# Double boot with 2 different SSD drives on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I think dual boot is on same drive, so I'm calling it double boot, maybe multi-boot is better. 4 year old system, I7-4790 3.6Ghz 16GB memory. Original Windows 7-64 is on a SSD. I've installed a new SSD. I have had various OS problems for months, but fiddling after every boot, the original OS boots and I can get work done. I tend to just leave it running. Can I load a fresh copy of Windows 7-64 on the new SSD and just switch the BIOS boot order to start one or the other? Bios is a Sabertooth Z87. Will windows get confused about which MBR is the right one, or will just switching the boot sequence make it work. Hoping someone has made it work before I go crazy trying.

Comment: " Can I load a fresh copy of Windows 7-64 on the new SSD and just switch the BIOS boot order to start one or the other?" Yes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe everybody else knows this and I just had to figure it out the hard way. So I tried what I described, loading a fresh copy of W7-64 on a new drive in my PC. First boot from the old C OS it disabled the new drive. Inspection told me it essentially could not handle two drives with a MBR. I had to let the partition manager change the new second drive to even access it. So the answer is no, you can't setup a PC with two drives having MBRs apparently.